# How to shift Bootstrap 4 navbar li elements to right?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to shift the li elements to right.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have alread tried this css code but it breaks the toggler and the navbar.

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    .pull-right();
    &:first-child {
      .pull-left();
    }
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

So I would like to shift the li elements without breaking the toggler or the navbar.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just text-aligning the elements in question? E.g: `.navbar-nav {
    text-align: right;
}`

Comment: Yeah. That didn't work.

Comment: That's strange, it works when I try it in-browser.

Comment: Well I am using codepen.

Comment: Then maybe try it in browser to see what I mean, or fork that a codepen so we can tinker around in whatever IDE you happen to be using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `justify-content-end` and remove `mr-auto`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

(I tested this solution without your css)

Comment: Nah. That didn't work. I'm getting the same. Also I am not using any external CSS except Bootstrap.

Comment: Right, I edited my answer, with `justify-content-end` it works fine for me

Comment: @zdolny if it works fine, just share it in snippet.

Comment: Perfect. That works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this class

```
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: right;
 }
```

and remove your classes

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
 .navbar-nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    .pull-right();
      &:first-child {
    .pull-left();
    }
   }
   .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Nope. That didn't work at all.